# Get values from one specific column in datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

i'm making a vocabulary trainer via visual C#. I'm storing words in `data grid view table`, where I have colums

- word
- grammatic
- translation
- language
- and unit.

I need to get all words (values from column called word) to be able to create some sort of test.

User will choose from which **language** (for example english) and from which **unit** (for example weather) he wants to be tested.
After pressing a button called `Test`, another form will be opened and the data in `data grid view table` will be filtered with two filters - language and unit (I managed to solve this problem). In the open form there will be two `labels` and a `button`. Instead of text of the first label there should be a word from the `datagridview table`, after pressing the button also translation should be shown - instead of text of the second label.

Could anyone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cname"].Value.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the data saved in multidimensional array to be able to have acces to them in loop with condition